# How to access DataGridView from another Winform and show its data in TextBox

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

I have 2 Forms, both forms have separate datagridview. In form 1 I have a data entry form where multiple text fields are there. In Form1, I want Doctor textfield to get data as I enter from datagridview2 (column 1 Dr.Name) that is in Form2 and keep data in Docotr filed and Fees should be kept in Fees textbox related to that Dr. who is in Docotor field.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How can I do that?

These are the codes of datagridview2 & this datagridview2  shoud be called when the user goes on Docotr Textbox filed.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AhsanHospital.Forms
{
    public partial class DoctorDetailsForm : Form
    {
        public DoctorDetailsForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
    }
        int Doctor_ID;
        


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\db\MyDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtDoctorName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please insert Docotr Name", "Empty Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                txtDoctorName.Focus();
            }


            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Doctor_Details Values (@DrName,@DrDegree,@DrTiming,@DrMobile,@DrAddress,@DrFees )", conn);

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrName", txtDoctorName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrDegree", txtDoctorDegree.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrTiming", txtDoctorTiming.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrMobile", txtDoctorMobile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrAddress", txtDoctorAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrFees", txtDoctroFees.Text);
   

                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("New Doctor Added Successfully", "Doctor Added", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                txtDoctorName.Focus();
                GetPatientRecord();
                ClearFields();
              
            }
        }

        private void GetPatientRecord()
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Doctor_Details ORDER BY DoctorId", conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader sdr = command.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(sdr);
            conn.Close();
            dgvDoctorDetails.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void ClearFields()
        {
            Doctor_ID = 0;
            txtDoctorid.Clear();
            txtDoctorName.Clear();
            txtDoctorAddress.Clear();
            txtDoctorDegree.Clear();
            txtDoctorMobile.Clear();
            txtDoctorTiming.Clear();
            txtDoctroFees.Clear();
            txtDoctorName.Focus();
            btnSave.Enabled = true;
        }

        private void DoctorDetailsForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetPatientRecord();
        }

        private void DoctorDetailsForm_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        { 
                if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
                {
                    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
                }
            
        }

       

        private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                if (txtDoctorName.Text == "" || txtDoctroFees.Text == "")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Please fill all the required fields", "Empty Data", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    txtDoctorName.Focus();
                
                }
            else
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Doctor_Details SET Doctor_Name=@DrName,Doctor_Degree=@DrDegree,Doctor_Timing=@DrTiming,Doctor_Mobile=@DrMobile,Doctor_Address=@DrAddress,Doctor_Fees=@DrFees WHERE DoctorId =@DrID", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrName", txtDoctorName.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrDegree", txtDoctorDegree.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrTiming", txtDoctorTiming.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrMobile", txtDoctorMobile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrAddress", txtDoctorAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrFees", txtDoctroFees.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrID", this.Doctor_ID);


                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Doctor Details Updated Successfully", "Doctor Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                GetPatientRecord();
                ClearFields();
                txtDoctorName.Focus();
            }

               




        }

        private void dgvDoctorDetails_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            btnSave.Enabled = false;
            Doctor_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);
            txtDoctorid.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            txtDoctorName.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtDoctorDegree.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtDoctorTiming.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtDoctorMobile.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txtDoctorAddress.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            txtDoctroFees.Text = dgvDoctorDetails.SelectedRows[0].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
           
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearFields();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you query directly from the database instead of accessing gridview of different form?

Comment: I have already done this using Textchange event on Doctor textfiled and made a query. I am getting the data but not able to keep it in Docotor text filed and also Dr fees in Fees text field.

Comment: It “appears” to me that the “Doctor” field in form 1, should be a `ComboBox` where the user could simply select the doctor and the fee would get set automatically. But this is pure speculation since it is unknown how the data is stored or how the grids are filled with data. Is there some reason you could not do this?

Comment: Both form's grids are showing data from an SQL table after inserting . As I am new here, so please let me explain how can I share my code here?

Comment: _”how can I share my code here?”_ … Click on the [edit] link under your question. Then simply copy and paste your code. To format it properly can be done by selecting the code in your question and click on the {} icon towards the top of the edit and it “should” format the code for you. However, some tweaking may be needed as the “auto” formatter is not perfect. You can scroll down and you should “see” the code as it would appear if you saved the changes.

Comment: Thanks JohnG. I have done as you suggested. Now look at my code.

Comment: As I previously commented… it would appear easier for you AND the user if you made the “Doctor” `TextBox` on the Patients Form a `ComboBox` where the user could simply select the doctor. Unless there are many-many doctors to choose from, this would be easier to code and definitely more user friendly. Is there some reason you do use this approach? You could use the List or Table of Doctors that shows in the Doctors detail form as a `DataSource` to the `ComboBox`. When the user “selects” a doctor from the combo box, then it should be trivial to get ALL the selected doctors info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out. I simply changed Dr. Name field from TextBox to ComboBox & created an Event called `SelectedIndexChanged`on Dr. Name ComboBox.

```
 private void cmbDoctorName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (cmbDoctorName.Text=="")
        {

        }
        else
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Doctor_Fees FROM Doctor_Details WHERE Doctor_Name='" + cmbDoctorName.SelectedItem.ToString() + "' ";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                txtCharges.Text = dr["Doctor_Fees"].ToString();
            }



            conn.Close();

        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use contractor and pass value from 1 form to other
in constructor you can pass specific value or you may pass object